# Error when trying to find 2nd maximum value in a list

Tags: python, list, max

I am trying to write code for finding the second maximum value of a list.

I tried it like this:

```
arr = map(int, input().split())
lista = list(arr)
max_value = lista[0]
run = lista[0]
for i in lista:
    if max_value < i:
        max_value = i
for j in lista:
    if run < j and run < max_value:
        run = j
print(run)
```

And the second maximum value and the maximum value comes out to be the same. What is the mistake in my program?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## The issue

### TLDR

```py
    run = lista[0]
    ...
    if run < j and run < max_value:
```

Should be

```py
          v
    run = min(lista)
    ...
                   v
    if run < j and j < max_value:
```

### How to find the Issue

#### 1. Make the code simpler

##### Comprehension instead of map - list constructor succession

We can reduce the boilerplate of firsts lines by using a comprehension instead of a succession of map and list constructors:

```py
arr = map(int, input().split())
lista = list(arr)
```

become:

```py
lista = [int(n) for n in input().split()]
```

##### Ask the max to Python, don't do it yourself

The next block of your logic is here to find the max of the list.
You don't need to write this code yourself, you can ask Python. This will reduce the complexity of your code, making the issue/bug easier to spot.

```py
max_value = lista[0]
for i in lista:
    if max_value < i:
        max_value = i
```

become:

```py
max_value = max(lista)
```

##### Rename variables

To help our brain understand what happens, let's clarify variables names:

```py
lista = [int(n) for n in input().split()]
max_value = max(lista)
run = lista[0]
for j in lista:
    if run < j and run < max_value:
        run = j
print(run)
```

become:

```py
user_input = [int(n) for n in input().split()]
max_value = max(user_input)

second_max = user_input[0]
for current_value in user_input:
    if second_max < current_value and second_max < max_value:
        second_max = current_value
        
print(second_max)
```

#### 2. Find the issue

Now, the code is smaller, easier to understand, with less place for error. If there is an error, we don't have to look at many places.

What's wrong? `second_max` should be the 2nd maximum value, but it's not.
What could cause that? An update of `previous_value` that shouldn't happen.

So this is where the issue might happen.

```py
    if second_max < current_value and second_max < max_value:
        second_max = current_value
```

The attribution is correct, the condition should be wrong.

This seems correct `second_max < current_value` since we want to update only if `second_max` is lower than current_value (meaning that current might be the true `second_max` value OR equal to `max_value`.
So we need another condition: `current_value` shouldn't be the `max_value`, otherwise, `second_max` might be set to the `max_value`.

And, we look at the second condition: `second_max < max_value`. Here is our mistake.

Let's fix the condition, since it's `current_value` that should be lower than `max_value`.
Also, the initial value of `second_max` need to be set at the minimum value in case the first value is the max.

```py
user_input = [int(n) for n in input().split()]
max_value = max(user_input)

second_max = min(user_input)
for current_value in user_input:
    if second_max < current_value and current_value < max_value:
        second_max = current_value

print(second_max)  # 55
```

Done.

### Alternative: Use set, sorted and index

If you want the second maximum value in a list, it is easier to sort a de-duplicated list and print the element at index 1 of the list e.g. the second element.

### Step by Step Example

```py
without_duplicates = {int(n) for n in input().split()}
ordered_without_duplicates = sorted(without_duplicates, reverse=True)
print(ordered_without_duplicates[1])
```

### Oneliner Example

```py
print(sorted({int(n) for n in input().split()}, reverse=True)[1])
```

### With heapq

```py
print(heapq.nlargest(2, {int(n) for n in input().split()})[1])
```

Comment: the second maximum value comes out to be 4 if the input is [4,4,-4,4]

Comment: the problem with the above exception is that it starts the runner value(second max) as the maximum value and stays the same throughout the loop

Comment: @blue `= min()` should works

Answer (score 4):

The test in your second loop is incorrect, use this:

```
arr = map(int, input().split())
lista = list(arr)
max_value = lista[0]
run = lista[0]
for i in lista:
    if max_value < i:
        max_value = i
for j in lista:
    if run<j and j!=max_value:
        run = j
print(run)
```

The checked value (`j`) should not be equal to the `max_value`.

Answer (score 2):

Interestingly, your method (with the logic correction) is **very fast** compared with other [common ways](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-program-to-find-second-largest-number-in-a-list/) of doing this. It is `f1` in the benchmark below.

Here is an online [BENCHMARK](https://tio.run/##jVdLc5tIEL77V0y8tQXjjLDAiZOiwl73uoe9sRSFpRkbmVdgsHG59Nu93cPwGMBOqBJC091fv5tW9SIfyuLm7S3Nq7KWpE6KY5mTC/1TpjknFxdHLohw7SxtZEL9CwJXnnQug5tHAhIqQriPoitPEUVZk5SkBVGEXgCvVCg58oOk0@GABkCpcThCnd6F8n6cCFhMTp8ChFiBonUndVhz2dbFZLZ2yls5hUD6cEvQbrjU5N0rHp6phroxoLSYbKuM2w3Ekh9nojTceX4U@v7OjQb5LytTwPiFMdql8ZSRR/4SZEl@d0xI55M8LQbjXAyR3ZFAsbuU8KzhpNt0yhty/PWX4UBuddap1HRjalBdB5lVyj5Ucmso0ZX2wJPqpzrAJywqe9cxsHehJhp5fjp4T8WLjd@9ypgpmydyVVZLsvcu@T2Dv32YGah71tsWQjKJkachHVs8BTBkvJgHd@wbaMN7bnusoD6Zl3wPkUbkL2XGjGhWh7vVXaPwSOTZCtNT/aQkPk0i24oGqonXawsMMM8AM7A@wjMmwSo7PalP0ffNwvWCIfpjePn2LOFDRFd@BpvhDLjptJb3NuT5B9Zr8w95JR94w23RFoeGkaS@bwKbMnIoZODu93sGFSF58G/dcgZVdahL9azdvby8/JsXHFlIQv7hdUYa@ZJxgnAyLQtyx4vDQ57Uj8BK1pdCQUOqqk4LGcvkDqaWutPJI5CdYSsqKVtZtRIoI5dKR1nniYxFyrOjre6MiFwG1qvPnL04W9SMEwRQvlS8Z6UkbUBH7Q8xU6e/4Fdz1pSATnN6Q3o@qAJqoAzMuTT46BQS4wEdu@cyhuzFhzKLn/sAMSioI@8WHk3ptkNsciMidfkcKqGI9uMNDrAsFV5EyUr1@IB6q@R4TAsokHDbGrocI6hfETECdOouxca0bl60uaqgVdrx@gMmlZCo3vSyfMZaCUL0aB852altpD03ElVGC6iaN5KUkMIHjojNFuTnIFyF7BRRp15rgONpS@g9dhn6DDJ0oVyVt20RyzmVqeJAZZRuNsRi@jRtJpvg9bw1qaFPZxFDokCiamczkjB4ahngXuVUvBaQu7aQvI6LxjarU9hXOAboQrqsfkdYW@vAxgFlm8CzLZw4LpKcxzEjIUQSXn68gJ0EEHfKKGr6@eiLrISeaNrcfqL0GiP61Ef6kT0p17WSVPIcDDjPlrakkZDkQO89mpHhrjIIQe3CUONPvG76udarV8UXhKFlRX3moNWxKn0yVPBguIXH1w0/WHRgVINxg/O/dn9zdwDW6yppGmumCbl4J5FL20zNN4U@nXIo8yoIeTR/dyj7jPAD06gcRt7ZGgYMVl8NSQN1KrhYN1c44OFy9tc6OIBP4brYrMjRz480Oq6YlE6o15PW9@DHbWvluVbeBQFmY6Zvt7NMMNw0/YVJjvvnZNFoUhftZj4b/k8Rx0QNSABKF3Nx451F3nvHzW7gytAQQWDFMEjTIo6t3l@1IMBYU/@GHPzCzO1cfsvg03dBPJs3mD89alTPw/RymfCYuGHiCxNfmbhl4hsT36dFZDYg9FgS1uvUpGefvAq91Jx1fJdrQv@/C95qb2//Aw).

And the code if you want to try on your own computer:

```
import random 
import time 

def f1(lista):
    max1,max2 = [lista[0]]*2
    for i in lista:
        if max1 < i:
            max1 = i
            
    for j in lista:
        if max2<j and j!=max1:
            max2 = j
    return max1,max2

def f2(lista):
    max1=max(lista)
    return max1,max(set(lista)-{max1})

def f3(lista):
    return tuple(sorted(set(lista))[-2:][::-1])

def f4(lista):
    max1 = max(lista)
    max2 = max(lista, key=lambda x: min(lista)-1 if (x == max1) else x)
    return max1,max2 

def f5(lista):
    max1=max(lista)
    max2=max(x for x in lista if x < max1)
    return max1,max2 

def f6(lista):
    import heapq
    heap = [(-x, x) for x in lista]
    heapq.heapify(heap)
    _,max1=heapq.heappop(heap)
    _,max2=heapq.heappop(heap)
    return max1,max2 

def f7(lista):
    max1 = max(lista[0], lista[1]) 
    max2 = min(lista[0], lista[1]) 
    n = len(lista)
    for i in range(2,n): 
        if lista[i] > max1: 
            max2 = max1
            max1 = lista[i] 
        elif lista[i] > max2 and max1 != lista[i]: 
            max2 = lista[i]
        elif max1 == max2 and max2 != lista[i]:
                max2 = lista[i]
                
    return max1,max2      

def f8(lista):
    max1=max2=lista[0]
    for e in lista:
        if e > max1:
            max2=max1
            max1=e
        elif e > max2:
            max2=e
    return max1,max2       

def cmpthese(funcs, args=(), cnt=1000, rate=True, micro=True):
    """Generate a Perl style function benchmark"""                   
    def pprint_table(table):
        """Perl style table output"""
        def format_field(field, fmt='{:,.0f}'):
            if type(field) is str: return field
            if type(field) is tuple: return field[1].format(field[0])
            return fmt.format(field)     
        
        def get_max_col_w(table, index):
            return max([len(format_field(row[index])) for row in table])         
        
        col_paddings=[get_max_col_w(table, i) for i in range(len(table[0]))]
        for i,row in enumerate(table):
            # left col
            row_tab=[row[0].ljust(col_paddings[0])]
            # rest of the cols
            row_tab+=[format_field(row[j]).rjust(col_paddings[j]) for j in range(1,len(row))]
            print(' '.join(row_tab))                
            
    results={}
    for i in range(cnt):
        for f in funcs:
            start=time.perf_counter_ns()
            f(*args)
            stop=time.perf_counter_ns()
            results.setdefault(f.__name__, []).append(stop-start)
    results={k:float(sum(v))/len(v) for k,v in results.items()}     
    fastest=sorted(results,key=results.get, reverse=True)
    table=[['']]
    if rate: table[0].append('rate/sec')
    if micro: table[0].append('\u03bcsec/pass')
    table[0].extend(fastest)
    for e in fastest:
        tmp=[e]
        if rate:
            tmp.append('{:,}'.format(int(round(float(cnt)*1000000.0/results[e]))))
            
        if micro:
            tmp.append('{:,.1f}'.format(results[e]/float(cnt)))
            
        for x in fastest:
            if x==e: tmp.append('--')
            else: tmp.append('{:.1%}'.format((results[x]-results[e])/results[e]))
        table.append(tmp) 
        
    pprint_table(table)                    
    
if __name__=='__main__':
    lista=[random.randint(-1e6,1e6) for _ in range(100000)]
    funcs=[f1,f2,f3,f4,f5,f6,f7,f8]
    for f in funcs: print(f'{f.__name__}: {f(lista)}')
    cmpthese(funcs, [lista])
```

On a recent Mac, this prints:

```
f1: (999991, 999978)
f2: (999991, 999978)
f3: (999991, 999978)
f4: (999991, 999978)
f5: (999991, 999978)
f6: (999991, 999978)
f7: (999991, 999978)
f8: (999991, 999978)
   rate/sec μsec/pass     f3     f6     f2     f4     f5     f7     f1     f8
f3      104   9,656.6     --  -3.1% -11.4% -45.9% -61.6% -71.2% -82.9% -87.3%
f6      107   9,358.3   3.2%     --  -8.6% -44.1% -60.3% -70.3% -82.3% -86.9%
f2      117   8,557.1  12.8%   9.4%     -- -38.9% -56.6% -67.5% -80.7% -85.7%
f4      191   5,227.9  84.7%  79.0%  63.7%     -- -29.0% -46.8% -68.3% -76.5%
f5      269   3,712.2 160.1% 152.1% 130.5%  40.8%     -- -25.1% -55.4% -66.9%
f7      360   2,779.1 247.5% 236.7% 207.9%  88.1%  33.6%     -- -40.4% -55.9%
f1      604   1,655.3 483.4% 465.3% 416.9% 215.8% 124.3%  67.9%     -- -25.9%
f8      815   1,226.9 687.1% 662.8% 597.5% 326.1% 202.6% 126.5%  34.9%     --
```

Comment: If this is indubitably interesting, I don't think performance is what Blue asked about.

Comment: I have updated the correct code in the answers,it may take longer now ig

Comment: It may be fast without the exception of the list starting with a max value

Comment: But I'm curious,which is faster for finding max value of list: max(list) or using for loop?

Comment: Should be max(list), it’s implemented in C if you are using CPython, where the for loop is pure python.

Answer (score 2):

I would write the code like this:

```
from heapq import nlargest
from typing import List

def second_largest(values: List[int]) -> int:
    result = nlargest(2, set(values))
    return result[1]
```

The code is more testable with the function split out. The caller similar to the poster's code would look like:

```
def second_largest_helper(value_str: str) -> int:
    return second_largest(map(int, value_str.split()))
```

The code raises an IndexError exception if there is a single unique value or no values in the list passed in.

Here is simple test data I tested with:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_data = [
        ([2, 2, 3, 5, 4, 6, 5, 3, 7], 6),
        ([2, 2, 3, 5, 4, 6, 5, 3], 5),
        ([2, 2, 3, 5, 4, 5, 3], 4),
        ([2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3], 4),
        ([2, 2, 3, 4, 3], 3),
        ([2, 2, 3, 3], 2),
        ([2, 2, 3], 2),
    ]
    for data, expected in test_data:
        print(f"{data = } {expected = }")
        assert second_largest(data) == expected
```

---

2023-11-14

You can write the code like this for the benchmarking code below:

```
def second_largest(values: List[int]) -> int:
    return nlargest(2, set(values))
```

or like this for datasets with few duplicates:

```
def second_largest(values: List[int]) -> int:
    return nlargest(2, values)
```

The second implementation is the fastest alternative so far, according to the benchmarking code, running 66% faster than f8.

Comment: "The code is more testable with the function split out." Pff, you can use subprocess.run to test it without function, it works like a charm ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
def second_max(arr):
    first=second=0
    for i in arr:
        if i> first:
            second=first
            first=i
        elif i> second:
            second=i
    return second
```

Comment: Great contribution, but `first=second=0` *should be* `first=second=arr[0]`. What if all the entries in `arr` are negative?

Answer (score 0):

The answers couldn't solve the exception where the list starts with the max value. To solve it,

```
lista = [int(n) for n in input().split()]
max_value = max(lista)
for a in lista:
    if a != max_value:
        run = a
for j in lista:
    if run<j and j!=max_value:
        run = j
print(run)
```

In second `for`,`j!=max_value` and `j<max_value` both work.